# Itcl: inconsistency of $this variable

Tags: tcl, itcl

While doing my project migration from Tcl 8.5.9/Itcl 3.4 to Tcl 8.6.6/Itcl 4.0.5 I've faced with inconsistency of `$this` variable depending how it's accessed. Here is the minimized testcase:

```
puts "Tcl  version : $tcl_patchLevel"
puts "Itcl version : [package require Itcl]"

itcl::class Base {
    public {
        method base_process {script} {
            uplevel $m_main main_process [list $script]
        }
        method set_main {main} {
          set m_main $main
        }
    }
    protected {
        variable m_main
    }
}

itcl::class Main {
  inherit Base
    public {
        method main_process {script} {
            uplevel $script
        }
    }
}

itcl::class Worker {
  inherit Base
    public {
        method worker_process_direct {} {
            puts "Direct query: this = $this"
        }
        method worker_process_inderect {} {
            base_process {puts "Indirect query: this = $this"}
        }
        method worker_process_both {} {
            puts "Direct query: this = $this"
            base_process {puts "Indirect query: this = $this"}
        }
    }
}

Main main

Worker worker
worker set_main main

puts "\n==== worker_process_direct   ===="
worker worker_process_direct

puts "\n==== worker_process_indirect ===="
worker worker_process_inderect

puts "\n==== worker_process_both     ===="
worker worker_process_both
```

`worker_process_direct` and `worker_process_both` functions always provide correct results. But `worker_process_inderect` works correctly only with old version of Tcl/Itcl. For Tcl 8.6.6/Itcl 4.0.5 `$this` variable is strangely changed to the instance of `Main` class instead of `Worker`.

Here is the output of the script above for two versions of Tcl/Itcl.

```
Tcl  version : 8.5.9
Itcl version : 3.4

==== worker_process_direct   ====
Direct query: this = ::worker

==== worker_process_indirect ====
Indirect query: this = ::worker          <<<<<<<<<<<< CORRECT

==== worker_process_both     ====
Direct query: this = ::worker
Indirect query: this = ::worker
```

```
Tcl  version : 8.6.6
Itcl version : 4.0.5

==== worker_process_direct   ====
Direct query: this = ::worker

==== worker_process_indirect ====
Indirect query: this = ::main            <<<<<<<<<< INCORRECT

==== worker_process_both     ====
Direct query: this = ::worker
Indirect query: this = ::worker
```

Did I miss something and there were significant changes in Tcl/Itcl which I haven't noticed?

Comment: Well, you _are_ using a different major version of itcl… I can reproduce with Tcl 8.6.3 and Itcl 4.0.2.

Comment: **tl;dr**: Looks like you found an itcl bug. Lucky you.

Answer (score 2):

Now that is *very* curious! I augmented your script to define `Main` like this:

```
itcl::class Main {
    inherit Base
    public {
        method main_process {script} {
            uplevel $script
            # Print what is actually going on!
            puts >>[tcl::unsupported::disassemble script $script]<<
        }
    }
}
```

With 8.5/3.4 I get this output:

```
Tcl  version : 8.5.9
Itcl version : 3.4

==== worker_process_direct   ====
Direct query: this = ::worker

==== worker_process_indirect ====
Indirect query: this = ::worker
>>ByteCode 0x0x7fedea044c10, refCt 1, epoch 3, interp 0x0x7fedea033010 (epoch 3)
  Source "puts \"Indirect query: this = $this\""
  Cmds 1, src 35, inst 12, litObjs 3, aux 0, stkDepth 3, code/src 0.00
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-10, src 0-34
  Command 1: "puts \"Indirect query: this = $this\""
    (0) push1 0     # "puts"
    (2) push1 1     # "Indirect query: this = "
    (4) push1 2     # "this"
    (6) loadScalarStk 
    (7) concat1 2 
    (9) invokeStk1 2 
    (11) done 
<<

==== worker_process_both     ====
Direct query: this = ::worker
Indirect query: this = ::worker
>>ByteCode 0x0x7fedea044c10, refCt 1, epoch 3, interp 0x0x7fedea033010 (epoch 3)
  Source "puts \"Indirect query: this = $this\""
  Cmds 1, src 35, inst 12, litObjs 3, aux 0, stkDepth 3, code/src 0.00
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-10, src 0-34
  Command 1: "puts \"Indirect query: this = $this\""
    (0) push1 0     # "puts"
    (2) push1 1     # "Indirect query: this = "
    (4) push1 2     # "this"
    (6) loadScalarStk 
    (7) concat1 2 
    (9) invokeStk1 2 
    (11) done 
<<
```

With 8.6/4.0 I get this instead:

```
Tcl  version : 8.6.3
Itcl version : 4.0.2

==== worker_process_direct   ====
Direct query: this = ::worker

==== worker_process_indirect ====
Indirect query: this = ::main
>>ByteCode 0x0x1009af010, refCt 1, epoch 136, interp 0x0x100829a10 (epoch 136)
  Source "puts \"Indirect query: this = $this"...
  Cmds 1, src 35, inst 12, litObjs 3, aux 0, stkDepth 3, code/src 0.00
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-10, src 0-34
  Command 1: "puts \"Indirect query: this = $this"...
    (0) push1 0     # "puts"
    (2) push1 1     # "Indirect query: this = "
    (4) push1 2     # "this"
    (6) loadStk 
    (7) strcat 2 
    (9) invokeStk1 2 
    (11) done 
<<

==== worker_process_both     ====
Direct query: this = ::worker
Indirect query: this = ::worker
>>ByteCode 0x0x1009b0210, refCt 1, epoch 136, interp 0x0x100829a10 (epoch 136)
  Source "puts \"Indirect query: this = $this"...
  Cmds 1, src 35, inst 11, litObjs 2, aux 0, stkDepth 3, code/src 0.00
  Commands 1:
      1: pc 0-9, src 0-34
  Command 1: "puts \"Indirect query: this = $this"...
    (0) push1 0     # "puts"
    (2) push1 1     # "Indirect query: this = "
    (4) loadScalar1 %v0 
    (6) strcat 2 
    (8) invokeStk1 2 
    (10) done 
<<
```

So, 8.5 uses the `loadScalarStk` instruction to read the variable in both (indirect) cases, whereas 8.6 uses `loadStk` and `loadScalar1` to load the variable in the two cases. Which is mighty strange; I wouldn't expect `loadScalar1` to appear in a script fragment (it needs a Local Variable Table) but at least it is picking up the expected value, whereas `loadStk` is just picking up the wrong value entirely. I've also tried using exactly the same value in the two places — with the script kept in a shared variable — but that produces the same output; it looks like in one place it is evaluating but picking up the wrong value (perhaps a variable resolver issue?) and in the other it is picking up the right value but for the wrong reasons (as the LVT shouldn't be used in a script fragment; that's for full procedures/methods only). Either way, it's Bad News.

Please file a bug report at http://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/tktnew as this smells like several sorts of wrong behaviour compounded.

Comment: Ok. Filed the ticket then - http://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/tktview/a1d08eb5353fd6fc39ed8b480f011af7bd875666

Comment: Following up: the `loadStk`/`loadScalarStk` difference doesn't matter; that was just effectively a renaming.

Comment: I've poked around more and I think this is a bug in incrTcl; converting the code to pure base TclOO (which itcl 4 builds on) makes it work as expected.

Comment: And in fact, the changes to the bytecodes are all exactly as expected. I believe this is an incr Tcl bug, probably in a variable resolver installed by the extension. Variable resolvers look tricky to write, but are _actually much more difficult than that,_ which is why we never actually exposed them in Tcl's public documented supported API.